# Pass multiple params to a tailwind plugin

Tags: tailwind-css

I have written this plugin to create a style of a border gradient element:

```js
    plugin(function ({matchUtilities, theme, }) {
      matchUtilities(
        {
          'border-gradient-primary': (background) => ({
            'border': '1px solid transparent',
            'background-image': `linear-gradient(to right, ${background}, ${background}),linear-gradient(94deg, rgba(149, 78, 245, 0.6) 0.69%, rgba(166, 118, 171, 0.6) 100%)`,
            'background-clip': 'padding-box, border-box',
            'background-origin': 'padding-box, border-box'
          }),
        },
        {
          values: Object.assign(
            theme('borderGradBg1', {}), 
            {
              'bg-gray-scale-500': myTheme["gray-scale"]["500"],
              'bg-primary-scale-600': myTheme["primary-scale"]["600"], 
              'bg-primary-scale-800': myTheme["primary-scale"]["800"],
            }
          )
        }
      )
    })
```

the `background-image` css attribute set the border to be a gradient and it accepts the background of the element as a value.
I want to extend this plugin so the background itself can also be a gradient, so I can do:

```scss
linear-gradient(to right, ${background1}, ${background2}),linear-gradient(94deg, rgba(149, 78, 245, 0.6) 0.69%, rgba(166, 118, 171, 0.6) 100%)
```